# Flutter Bluetooth Background Mode iOS - keep app alive, listening to BLE characteristic notifications

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-service

actually I'm pretty new to Flutter and mobile app development. Currently I'm working on an app in Flutter, receiving data from a sensor, connected via BLE (flutter_blue_plus) to the mobile device.
Now I have problems with iOS, that keeps killing my app, as soon it goes in background mode (lockscreen or minimization).
I tried bunch of different approaches (flutter_background_service, etc.), but none of them worked so far. With flutter_background_service, the app is getting killed approx. 20 seconds after entering background mode.
I can't find clear informations online, if it is even possible to keep the app alive on iOS, when using Flutter. The statements i found on this are very contradictory.

Thank you very much nad best reagrds

I tried bunch of different approaches (flutter_background_services, etc.), but none of them worked so far. With flutter_background_service, the app is getting killed approx. 20 seconds after entering background mode.

Comment: Have you read about State Preservation and Restoration? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW10

Answer (score 2):

Nice to see new flutter devs working with BLE ;)

## Info.plist changes

Try adding this change to your `Info.plist` file (found in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`). It might do the trick.

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app uses bluetooth to find, connect and transfer data between different devices</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app uses bluetooth to find, connect and transfer data between different devices</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>bluetooth-central</string>
</array>
```

Note: after having added this it is wise to run `flutter clean` and then fully restart and reinstall the app you have on your device, because this touches the underlying config.

Source: this comment on the [GitHub repo for a BLE library](https://github.com/dotintent/FlutterBleLib/issues/530#issuecomment-700412023). It is a different library than you use but it gives a clue into how this file works.

If you want to dive deeper into iOS and Bluetooth [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) is their official (and complicated) documentation on this.

## Alternative solution

If you want evade sleeping in general: consider adding a wakelock. See the [wakelock package](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock).